# Can I add a messageListener to an xslt Template object?

Tags: xslt, sax

I would like to add a feature to capture xsl:message outputs to an existing application.  Found straightforward refs to add messageListener to a transformer but my app consists of a saxTransformerFactory.newTemplates() generating a templates object which is then used to create an xmlfilter, "XMLFilter xmlFilter = saxTransformerFactory.newXMLFilter(templates);".  How do I bolt in my class that "implements MessageListener"?

Answer (score 1):

The TransformerFactory and related classes are a product-independent API (called JAXP, or sometimes Trax) for invoking XSLT processors. The MessageListener is specific to the Saxon product. You can register a MessageListener with Saxon's Controller object, which is the Saxon implementation of the JAXP Transformer. If you have a JAXP Transformer you need to cast the Transformer to a Saxon Controller, and then call setMessageListener. When you use an XMLFilter with Saxon, the XMLFilter will be an instance of net.sf.saxon.Filter. This has a getTransformer() method, which returns the Controller.

Comment: In fact my XMLFilter is an instance of org.xml.sax.XMLFilter which does not appear to have a getTranformer() method.  I guess I will have to live without capturing xsl:message!

Comment: org.xml.sax.XMLFilter is an interface, so anything that implements this interface will also belong to a concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Michael Kay, but then more in Java Code ;-)

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
if (transformer instanceof TransformerImpl) {
   //saxon specific
   TransformerImpl timpl = (TransformerImpl) transformer;
   XsltTransformer saxonTransformer = timpl.getUnderlyingXsltTransformer();
   saxonTransformer.setMessageListener( ...your listener... );
}
```